# RStudio floating function and rm()

Tags: rstudio

When I hover my cursor over a line of my script with a function, a little window with the function structure hovers at the tip of my cursor. This can be either the actual function or rm().

[image]

[image]

Questions:

1. How do I turn this feature off in RStudio?
2. When you click at a function already typed or when you type a function, RStudio should have a feature to display the function and its arguments at the border between the editor and console panels. Now sure how this feature is turned on.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean re: question 2.

Comment: @Phil Can you check my revised question #2 above?

Comment: I'm not familiar of such a feature.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding question 1, uncheck the option "Show help tooltip after function completions" in Global Options -> Code -> Completion window.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this solves the first problem.